# Why is the map $ F: GL(2,\mathbb{C}) \mapsto \mathrm{Aut}(\hat{\mathbb{C}})$ surjective?

Tags: complex-analysis

Why is the map $ F: GL(2,\mathbb{C}) \mapsto \mathrm{Aut}(\hat{\mathbb{C}})$ surjective?

$F\space \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
a & b  \\
c & d  \\
 \end{array} \right) \mapsto (z \mapsto \frac{az+b}{cz+d})$

I.e why can every conformal bijection of $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$ be written as a Mobius map?

I am told that the proof of this requires Liouville's Theorem and other results of complex analysis. But I am not seeing it.

Answer (score 1):

You can check that Möbius maps act transitivaly on $\widehat{\mathbb C}$. In particular, by composing with a suitable Möbius map you can reduce to the case of Aut$(\mathbb C)$. Those are polynomials of degree 1, which are Möbius.